# CC2538 bare metal project compile but doesn't work

Tags: c, embedded, bare-metal, linker-scripts, texas-instruments

I'm new to embedded development and I'm currently trying to develop a project for a custom board based on TI's CC2538SF53 microcontroller. I've based the code on some tutorials I've seen online and on the code used in Contiki's repository in Github.

I can compile and link my project just fine, but I still can't make my program run in the board so I assume I must be mapping my memory wrong or something.

I tested the board with different binaries compiled for this it and they work just fine. I don't have access to the source code from which those binaries were compiled so I can't use them as reference.

Does anyone have any experience with this chip? Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here's my startup and linker files:

*Edit: While answering one comment I've realized that it might be useful to have the full source code and the binaries compiled from it so I'll leave here a link to a Drive folder containing those: [Full Project (binaries in build subdir)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gK_KRjwy_wouUBX_TZ38XDb0erzUXFog?usp=drive_link)*

**startup.c**

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include "eposInterrupts.h"   // Interrupt handlers are defined here

#define FLASH_START_ADDR            0x00200000  //* Flash start address *//
#define FLASH_IMAGE_VALID           0x00000000  //* Identifies that the image in flash is valid *//
#define BOOTLOADER_BACKDOOR_ENABLE  0xFFFFFFF9  //* Enables the Bootloader Backdoor on GPIOA1 *//

#define SRAM_START  0x20000000                  //* SRAM starting location *//
#define SRAM_LENGTH (16 * 1024)                 //* 16 kB *//

void reset_handler(void);

//*****************************************************************************
// Reserve space for the system stack.
//*****************************************************************************
__attribute__ ((section(".stack"), used))
static uint32_t stack[128];

__attribute__ ((section(".vectors"), used))
void (* const vectors[])(void) = {
   (void (*)(void))((uint32_t)stack + sizeof(stack)),       // 0 Stack pointer
   reset_handler,                                           // 1 Reset handler
   NMI_handler,                                             // 2 The NMI handler
   hard_fault_handler,                                      // 3 The hard fault handler
   mem_manage_fault_handler,                                // 4 The MPU fault handler
   bus_fault_handler,                                       // 5 The bus fault handler
   usage_fault_handler,                                     // 6 The usage fault handler
   0,                                                       // 7 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 8 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 9 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 10 Reserved
   sv_call_handler,                                         // 11 SVCall handler
   debug_monitor_handler,                                   // 12 Debug monitor handler
   0,                                                       // 13 Reserved
   pend_sv_call_handler,                                    // 14 The PendSV handler
   systick_handler,                                         // 15 The SysTick handler
   GPIOA_handler,                                           // 16 GPIO Port A
   GPIOB_handler,                                           // 17 GPIO Port B
   GPIOC_handler,                                           // 18 GPIO Port C
   GPIOD_handler,                                           // 19 GPIO Port D
   0,                                                       // 20 none
   UART0_handler,                                           // 21 UART0 Rx and Tx
   UART1_handler,                                           // 22 UART1 Rx and Tx
   SSI0_handler,                                            // 23 SSI0 Rx and Tx
   I2C_handler,                                             // 24 I2C Master and Slave
   0,                                                       // 25 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 26 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 27 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 28 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 29 Reserved
   ADC_handler,                                             // 30 ADC Sequence 0
   0,                                                       // 31 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 32 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 33 Reserved
   watchdog_handler,                                        // 34 Watchdog timer 
   timer0A_handler,                                         // 35 Timer 0 subtimer A
   timer0B_handler,                                         // 36 Timer 0 subtimer B
   timer1A_handler,                                         // 37 Timer 1 subtimer A
   timer1B_handler,                                         // 38 Timer 1 subtimer B
   timer2A_handler,                                         // 39 Timer 2 subtimer A
   timer2B_handler,                                         // 40 Timer 2 subtimer B
   analog_comparator_handler,                               // 41 Analog Comparator 0
   RF_Core_Rx_Tx_handler,                                   // 42 RFCore Rx/Tx (Alternate)
   RF_Core_error_handler,                                   // 43 RFCore Error (Alternate)
   system_control_handler,                                  // 44 IcePick
   flash_control_handler,                                   // 45 FLASH Control
   AES_handler,                                             // 46 AES (Alternate)
   PKA_handler,                                             // 47 PKA (Alternate)
   sleep_timer_handler,                                     // 48 Sleep Timer (Alternate)
   MAC_timer_handler,                                       // 49 MacTimer (Alternate)
   SSI1_handler,                                            // 50 SSI1 Rx and Tx
   timer3A_handler,                                         // 51 Timer 3 subtimer A
   timer3B_handler,                                         // 52 Timer 3 subtimer B
   0,                                                       // 53 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 54 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 55 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 56 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 57 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 58 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 59 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 60 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 61 Reserved
   uDMA_handler,                                            // 62 uDMA
   uDMA_error_handler,                                      // 63 uDMA Error
   0,                                                       // 64 Unused
   0,                                                       // 65 Unused
   0,                                                       // 66 Unused
   0,                                                       // 67 Unused
   0,                                                       // 68 Unused
   0,                                                       // 69 Unused
   0,                                                       // 70 Unused
   0,                                                       // 71 Unused
   0,                                                       // 72 Unused
   0,                                                       // 73 Unused
   0,                                                       // 74 Unused
   0,                                                       // 75 Unused
   0,                                                       // 76 Unused
   0,                                                       // 77 Unused
   0,                                                       // 78 Unused
   0,                                                       // 79 Unused
   0,                                                       // 80 Unused
   0,                                                       // 81 Unused
   0,                                                       // 82 Unused
   0,                                                       // 83 Unused
   0,                                                       // 84 Unused
   0,                                                       // 85 Unused
   0,                                                       // 86 Unused
   0,                                                       // 87 Unused
   0,                                                       // 88 Unused
   0,                                                       // 89 Unused
   0,                                                       // 90 Unused
   0,                                                       // 91 Unused
   0,                                                       // 92 Unused
   0,                                                       // 93 Unused
   0,                                                       // 94 Unused
   0,                                                       // 95 Unused
   0,                                                       // 96 Unused
   0,                                                       // 97 Unused
   0,                                                       // 98 Unused
   0,                                                       // 99 Unused
   0,                                                       // 100 Unused
   0,                                                       // 101 Unused
   0,                                                       // 102 Unused
   0,                                                       // 103 Unused
   0,                                                       // 104 Unused
   0,                                                       // 105 Unused
   0,                                                       // 106 Unused
   0,                                                       // 107 Unused
   0,                                                       // 108 Unused
   0,                                                       // 109 Unused
   0,                                                       // 110 Unused
   0,                                                       // 111 Unused
   0,                                                       // 112 Unused
   0,                                                       // 113 Unused
   0,                                                       // 114 Unused
   0,                                                       // 115 Unused
   0,                                                       // 116 Unused
   0,                                                       // 117 Unused
   0,                                                       // 118 Unused
   0,                                                       // 119 Unused
   0,                                                       // 120 Unused
   0,                                                       // 121 Unused
   0,                                                       // 122 Unused
   0,                                                       // 123 Unused
   0,                                                       // 124 Unused
   0,                                                       // 125 Unused
   0,                                                       // 126 Unused
   0,                                                       // 127 Unused
   0,                                                       // 128 Unused
   0,                                                       // 129 Unused
   0,                                                       // 130 Unused
   0,                                                       // 131 Unused
   0,                                                       // 132 Unused
   0,                                                       // 133 Unused
   0,                                                       // 134 Unused
   0,                                                       // 135 Unused
   0,                                                       // 136 Unused
   0,                                                       // 137 Unused
   0,                                                       // 138 Unused
   0,                                                       // 139 Unused
   0,                                                       // 140 Unused
   0,                                                       // 141 Unused
   0,                                                       // 142 Unused
   0,                                                       // 143 Unused
   0,                                                       // 144 Unused
   0,                                                       // 145 Unused
   0,                                                       // 146 Unused
   0,                                                       // 147 Unused
   0,                                                       // 148 Unused
   0,                                                       // 149 Unused
   0,                                                       // 150 Unused
   0,                                                       // 151 Unused
   0,                                                       // 152 Unused
   0,                                                       // 153 Unused
   0,                                                       // 154 Unused
   0,                                                       // 155 Unused
   USB_handler,                                             // 156 USB 2538
   RF_Core_Rx_Tx_handler,                                   // 157 RFCore Rx/Tx
   RF_Core_error_handler,                                   // 158 RFCore Error
   AES_handler,                                             // 159 AES
   PKA_handler,                                             // 160 PKA
   sleep_timer_handler,                                     // 161 Sleep Timer
   MAC_timer_handler,                                       // 162 MacTimer
};

//*****************************************************************************
// Customer Configuration Area in Lock Page
//*****************************************************************************
typedef struct {
    uint32_t bootloaderCfg;     // Bootloader backdoor
  uint32_t imageValid;        // Image valid bytes
  uint32_t vectorAddr;        // Vector table located at flash start address
  uint8_t  pageLockBits[32];  // Unlock all flash pages and debug access
} lockPageCCA_t;

__attribute__((section(".flashcca")))
const lockPageCCA_t cca_lock_page =
{
  BOOTLOADER_BACKDOOR_ENABLE,
  FLASH_IMAGE_VALID,
  (uint32_t)&vectors,
  {
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF 
  }
};

extern int main(void);

extern uint32_t _etext;
extern uint32_t _sdata;
extern uint32_t _edata;
extern uint32_t _sbss;
extern uint32_t _ebss;

void reset_handler (void) {
  uint32_t* source;
  uint32_t* destination;

    // Copy the data segment initializers from flash to SRAM.
    source = &_etext;
    for(destination = &_sdata; destination < &_edata; ) {
        *destination++ = *source++;
    }

    // Zero fill the bss segment.

  for(destination = &_sbss; destination < &_ebss; ) {
      *destination++ = 0;
  }
          
  // Call the application's entry point.
  main();

  // End here if return from main()
  while(1);
}
```

**linker.ld**

```
MEMORY {
    FLASH(rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00200000, LENGTH = 512K - 44
    FLASH_CCA(rx) : ORIGIN = ORIGIN(FLASH) + LENGTH(FLASH), LENGTH = 44
    SRAM_NON_RETENTION(rwx) : ORIGIN =  0x20000000, LENGTH = 16K
    SRAM_RETENTION(rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20004000, LENGTH = 16K - 512
    STACK(rwx) : ORIGIN = ORIGIN(SRAM_RETENTION) + LENGTH(SRAM_RETENTION), LENGTH = 512
}

ENTRY(reset_handler)

SECTIONS {
    /* Section in which code is placed */
    .text : {
        _stext = .;
        KEEP(*(.vectors*))
        *(.text*)
        *(.rodata*)
        _etext = .;
    } > FLASH

    /* Section in which initialized data is placed */
    .data : {
        _sdata = .;
        *(vtable)
        *(.data*)
        _edata = .;
    } > SRAM_RETENTION AT> FLASH
    
    /* Section in which uninitialized data is placed */
    .bss : {
        _sbss = .;
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        _ebss = .;
    } > SRAM_RETENTION

    /* Program stack */
    .stack : {
        KEEP(*(.stack))
    } > STACK

    /* Program heap is placed entirely on the non retention SRAM */
    _heap = ORIGIN(SRAM_NON_RETENTION);
    _eheap = ORIGIN(SRAM_NON_RETENTION) + LENGTH(SRAM_NON_RETENTION);
 
    .flashcca : { 
        *(.flashcca)
    } > FLASH_CCA   
}
```

Comment: Don't even think about writing your own start up code or doing anything complex unless you have debug support (a JTAG H/W debugger and source level debugger software).  TI almost certainly provide CMSIS compliant start-up code that will get you to `main()`.  I would suggest you start with that rather than extracting it from other projects.  This code certainly does not look "standard".

Comment: Why do you allocate the stack as an array of `uint64_t`? That's really strange and will cause all manner of undefined behavior problems in case you use gcc with strict aliasing enabled. Usually, the stack is not a declared type at all.

Comment: A better starting point perhaps https://www.ti.com/tool/CC2538-SW.  I believe it includes examples that will have suitable start-up code.

Comment: @Clifford I have setup my workspace for debugging with a J-link and GDB already. The debugger launches, goes to the entry point which is my reset_handler but can't go past the first line. I've checked TI's startup files also, that's one of the bases I've used for my code. I think my problem might be more in the linker script because I've tried to use their startup file and it failed as well.

Comment: @Lundin I've based it off of this startup file I've found in Contiki's repository https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/cpu/cc2538/startup-gcc.c . I thought it made sense, don't I have to reserve space for the stack? And if so and this is wrong, how should I do it?

Comment: @LucasYotsui If you don't allocate something in a certain memory range, then it is reserved. It is common to set aside room for the stack in the linker script but otherwise do nothing in the C code.

Comment: That information (about your GDB results) should be in the he question, not a comment.  Did you step at the assembly level to see precisely what it is running?  Does that assembly code correspond to the source code?  Does it even step?  Is the program- counter at  the expected address? Is the SP correct at that point (initial PC and SP are the first two words in the vector table and loaded on reset by hardware).

Comment: You create a static array for `stack`, but it is more normal to use a linker generated symbol for that.

Comment: @Clifford I'm not very familiar with assembly so I was trying to stay at C level, but I did check the PC and SP registers. The PC register points to my reset_handler so I guess that is correct and the SP points to 0x20007FD8, which I'm honestly not sure but it seems right since my stack top is 0x20008000. Still the debugger stops on the reset_handler and I can't even step into it. And about the static array, I just did it like that because that's how TI's example and the startup from Contiki do it and I'm new to linker scripts so I wasn't sure how to do it any other way.

Comment: It has to go somewhere when you step - what does the PC change to? If it does not change then there is something wrong with the debugger.  You don't need to be familiar with assembler to check the code is plausible or that the PC is progressing through the instructions.  My guess is that the flash has not been programmed and the debugger is simply overlaying the source over blank flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to make it work somehow!! Thanks a lot to everyone who took a minute to help me out here, it really helped. Honestly, I've made so many changes to my code that I'm not even sure what was it that made it work, but it did! I'll leave here the currently working version of the startup and linker files + the [Github repo](https://github.com/lucas-yotsui/Projeto-VSCode-EPOSMoteIII) of the project I'm working on (It's still a work in progress, but I think this was the most important step in it!) if you can check it out and maybe star it and give some feedback, I'd really appreciate it!

**startup.c**

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include "eposInterrupts.h"                     //* Interrupt handlers are defined here *//

#define FLASH_START_ADDR            0x00200000  //* Flash start address *//
#define FLASH_IMAGE_VALID           0x00000000  //* Identifies that the image in flash is valid *//
#define BOOTLOADER_BACKDOOR_DISABLE 0xEFFFFFFF  //* Disables the Bootloader Backdoor *//

#define STACK_TOP                   0x20008000

void reset_handler(void);

__attribute__ ((section(".vectors"), used))
void (* const vectors[])(void) = {
   (void (*)(void))STACK_TOP,                               // 0 Stack pointer
   reset_handler,                                           // 1 Reset handler
   NMI_handler,                                             // 2 The NMI handler
   hard_fault_handler,                                      // 3 The hard fault handler
   mem_manage_fault_handler,                                // 4 The MPU fault handler
   bus_fault_handler,                                       // 5 The bus fault handler
   usage_fault_handler,                                     // 6 The usage fault handler
   0,                                                       // 7 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 8 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 9 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 10 Reserved
   sv_call_handler,                                         // 11 SVCall handler
   debug_monitor_handler,                                   // 12 Debug monitor handler
   0,                                                       // 13 Reserved
   pend_sv_call_handler,                                    // 14 The PendSV handler
   systick_handler,                                         // 15 The SysTick handler
   GPIOA_handler,                                           // 16 GPIO Port A
   GPIOB_handler,                                           // 17 GPIO Port B
   GPIOC_handler,                                           // 18 GPIO Port C
   GPIOD_handler,                                           // 19 GPIO Port D
   0,                                                       // 20 none
   UART0_handler,                                           // 21 UART0 Rx and Tx
   UART1_handler,                                           // 22 UART1 Rx and Tx
   SSI0_handler,                                            // 23 SSI0 Rx and Tx
   I2C_handler,                                             // 24 I2C Master and Slave
   0,                                                       // 25 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 26 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 27 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 28 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 29 Reserved
   ADC_handler,                                             // 30 ADC Sequence 0
   0,                                                       // 31 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 32 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 33 Reserved
   watchdog_handler,                                        // 34 Watchdog timer 
   timer0A_handler,                                         // 35 Timer 0 subtimer A
   timer0B_handler,                                         // 36 Timer 0 subtimer B
   timer1A_handler,                                         // 37 Timer 1 subtimer A
   timer1B_handler,                                         // 38 Timer 1 subtimer B
   timer2A_handler,                                         // 39 Timer 2 subtimer A
   timer2B_handler,                                         // 40 Timer 2 subtimer B
   analog_comparator_handler,                               // 41 Analog Comparator 0
   RF_Core_Rx_Tx_handler,                                   // 42 RFCore Rx/Tx (Alternate)
   RF_Core_error_handler,                                   // 43 RFCore Error (Alternate)
   system_control_handler,                                  // 44 IcePick
   flash_control_handler,                                   // 45 FLASH Control
   AES_handler,                                             // 46 AES (Alternate)
   PKA_handler,                                             // 47 PKA (Alternate)
   sleep_timer_handler,                                     // 48 Sleep Timer (Alternate)
   MAC_timer_handler,                                       // 49 MacTimer (Alternate)
   SSI1_handler,                                            // 50 SSI1 Rx and Tx
   timer3A_handler,                                         // 51 Timer 3 subtimer A
   timer3B_handler,                                         // 52 Timer 3 subtimer B
   0,                                                       // 53 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 54 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 55 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 56 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 57 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 58 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 59 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 60 Reserved
   0,                                                       // 61 Reserved
   uDMA_handler,                                            // 62 uDMA
   uDMA_error_handler,                                      // 63 uDMA Error
   0,                                                       // 64 Unused
   0,                                                       // 65 Unused
   0,                                                       // 66 Unused
   0,                                                       // 67 Unused
   0,                                                       // 68 Unused
   0,                                                       // 69 Unused
   0,                                                       // 70 Unused
   0,                                                       // 71 Unused
   0,                                                       // 72 Unused
   0,                                                       // 73 Unused
   0,                                                       // 74 Unused
   0,                                                       // 75 Unused
   0,                                                       // 76 Unused
   0,                                                       // 77 Unused
   0,                                                       // 78 Unused
   0,                                                       // 79 Unused
   0,                                                       // 80 Unused
   0,                                                       // 81 Unused
   0,                                                       // 82 Unused
   0,                                                       // 83 Unused
   0,                                                       // 84 Unused
   0,                                                       // 85 Unused
   0,                                                       // 86 Unused
   0,                                                       // 87 Unused
   0,                                                       // 88 Unused
   0,                                                       // 89 Unused
   0,                                                       // 90 Unused
   0,                                                       // 91 Unused
   0,                                                       // 92 Unused
   0,                                                       // 93 Unused
   0,                                                       // 94 Unused
   0,                                                       // 95 Unused
   0,                                                       // 96 Unused
   0,                                                       // 97 Unused
   0,                                                       // 98 Unused
   0,                                                       // 99 Unused
   0,                                                       // 100 Unused
   0,                                                       // 101 Unused
   0,                                                       // 102 Unused
   0,                                                       // 103 Unused
   0,                                                       // 104 Unused
   0,                                                       // 105 Unused
   0,                                                       // 106 Unused
   0,                                                       // 107 Unused
   0,                                                       // 108 Unused
   0,                                                       // 109 Unused
   0,                                                       // 110 Unused
   0,                                                       // 111 Unused
   0,                                                       // 112 Unused
   0,                                                       // 113 Unused
   0,                                                       // 114 Unused
   0,                                                       // 115 Unused
   0,                                                       // 116 Unused
   0,                                                       // 117 Unused
   0,                                                       // 118 Unused
   0,                                                       // 119 Unused
   0,                                                       // 120 Unused
   0,                                                       // 121 Unused
   0,                                                       // 122 Unused
   0,                                                       // 123 Unused
   0,                                                       // 124 Unused
   0,                                                       // 125 Unused
   0,                                                       // 126 Unused
   0,                                                       // 127 Unused
   0,                                                       // 128 Unused
   0,                                                       // 129 Unused
   0,                                                       // 130 Unused
   0,                                                       // 131 Unused
   0,                                                       // 132 Unused
   0,                                                       // 133 Unused
   0,                                                       // 134 Unused
   0,                                                       // 135 Unused
   0,                                                       // 136 Unused
   0,                                                       // 137 Unused
   0,                                                       // 138 Unused
   0,                                                       // 139 Unused
   0,                                                       // 140 Unused
   0,                                                       // 141 Unused
   0,                                                       // 142 Unused
   0,                                                       // 143 Unused
   0,                                                       // 144 Unused
   0,                                                       // 145 Unused
   0,                                                       // 146 Unused
   0,                                                       // 147 Unused
   0,                                                       // 148 Unused
   0,                                                       // 149 Unused
   0,                                                       // 150 Unused
   0,                                                       // 151 Unused
   0,                                                       // 152 Unused
   0,                                                       // 153 Unused
   0,                                                       // 154 Unused
   0,                                                       // 155 Unused
   USB_handler,                                             // 156 USB 2538
   RF_Core_Rx_Tx_handler,                                   // 157 RFCore Rx/Tx
   RF_Core_error_handler,                                   // 158 RFCore Error
   AES_handler,                                             // 159 AES
   PKA_handler,                                             // 160 PKA
   sleep_timer_handler,                                     // 161 Sleep Timer
   MAC_timer_handler,                                       // 162 MacTimer
};

//*****************************************************************************
// Customer Configuration Area in Lock Page
//*****************************************************************************
typedef struct {
  uint32_t bootloaderCfg;     // Bootloader backdoor
  uint32_t imageValid;        // Image valid bytes
  uint32_t vectorAddr;        // Vector table located at flash start address
  uint8_t  pageLockBits[32];  // Unlock all flash pages and debug access
} lockPageCCA_t;

__attribute__((section(".flashcca"), used))
const lockPageCCA_t cca_lock_page =
{
  BOOTLOADER_BACKDOOR_DISABLE,
  FLASH_IMAGE_VALID,
  (uint32_t)&vectors, 
  { 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF
  }
};

extern int main(void);

extern uint32_t _etext;
extern uint32_t _sdata;
extern uint32_t _edata;
extern uint32_t _sbss;
extern uint32_t _ebss;

void reset_handler (void) {
  uint32_t* source;
  uint32_t* destination;

    // Copy the data segment initializers from flash to SRAM.
    source = &_etext;
    for(destination = &_sdata; destination < &_edata; ) {
        *destination++ = *source++;
    }

    // Zero fill the bss segment.

  for(destination = &_sbss; destination < &_ebss; ) {
      *destination++ = 0;
  }
          
  // Call the application's entry point.
  main();

  // End here if return from main()
  while(1);
}
```

**linker**

```
MEMORY {
    FLASH(rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00200000, LENGTH = 0x0007FFD4
    FLASH_CCA(rx) : ORIGIN = 0x0027FFD4, LENGTH = 0x0000002C
    SRAM_NON_RETENTION(rwx) : ORIGIN =  0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00004000
    SRAM_RETENTION(rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20004000, LENGTH = 0x00004000
    STACK(rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20007E00, LENGTH = 0x00000200
}

ENTRY(reset_handler)

SECTIONS {
    /* Section in which code is placed */
    .text : {
        _stext = .;
        KEEP(*(.vectors*))
        *(.text*)
        *(.rodata*)
        _etext = .;
    } > FLASH

    /* Section in which initialized data is placed */
    .data : {
        _sdata = .;
        *(vtable)
        *(.data*)
        _edata = .;
    } > SRAM_RETENTION AT> FLASH
    
    /* Section in which uninitialized data is placed */
    .bss : {
        _sbss = .;
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        _ebss = .;
    } > SRAM_RETENTION

    /* Program heap is placed entirely on the non retention SRAM */
    _heap = ORIGIN(SRAM_NON_RETENTION);
    _eheap = ORIGIN(SRAM_NON_RETENTION) + LENGTH(SRAM_NON_RETENTION);
 
    .flashcca : { 
        KEEP(*(.flashcca))
    } > FLASH_CCA   
}
```

Comment: I would say that this proves that the bug was as I expected: you gave the end address of the stack to the vector table, rather than the start address. Now that you moved the stack 0x200 bytes downwards but still init the stack to 0x20008000, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you compile with the correct compile options (minimum -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthubm)
2. Check if what you got is what you expect.

- extract the binary file from the elf (or if you use he debugger do not start the app - simple check the flash memory)
- check if the addresses in the vector table are correct (remember that they have to be ***odd*** to correctly indicate ***THUMB instructions!!!!!***, otherwise it will not work)

I would also

```
KEEP(*(.vectors*))
```

Comment: Here are the flags I've used. I've adapted them from a project I have for the Tiva board: **-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mfloat-abi=soft -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -MD -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti**

Comment: the last two are for  g++

Comment: did you check the file?

Comment: I know, I tried to make the project compatible with both gcc and g++. I didn't check the file because I honestly don't know how to do it. Do I call objdump on the .axf? If so, what will I be looking for?

Comment: Check the vector table first. Addresses have to be off. Of handler 0x800400 then address has to be 0x800401

Comment: Look I'm really sorry for the inexperience, but how do I check those addresses? I've called objdump on the binary but I honestly don't understand it. I'll put a link to a drive folder with my whole project and the executables built with it so you can check for yourself for any mistakes: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gK_KRjwy_wouUBX_TZ38XDb0erzUXFog?usp=drive_link

Comment: @LucasYotsui For embedded systems development, like any form of programming, you need to use a debugger. Embedded debuggers come with a memory map feature where you can type in an address and see what's stored there. Is the vector table really to be allocated at 0x200000 though? It's usually placed at address 0 but then I don't know anything of these TI parts.

Comment: @Lundin I've set up my debugging workspace already but I'm not very experienced with it so it hasn't been much help. I'll try to check the memory map with it and see if my addresses are right. About the 0x200000 adresss, the User Guide form TI says that the vector table should go on the start of the Flash, which is in that address.

Comment: @LucasYotsui if you are not experienced I would advise you to use CCSTUDIO to generate startup code, linker files etc. Start DIY solutions when you get some experience and you will simply be chasing your tail.

Comment: @gulpr Do you remember if the stack pointer must be an odd address as well - I think so? But the OP allocates it on an even address 0x20008000. Furthermore the stack is down-counting so maybe that's the actual bug. Maybe it should be 0x200087FF.

Comment: @Lundin no, it is an actual address. It is only when code branches to indicate the instruction set of the subroutine. Leftover from the machines supporting both.

Comment: Ok well I believe that's a bug still. It's a down-counting stack allocated between 0x20008000 and 0x20008800 so it shouldn't get initialized to the address of the `stack` C variable located at 0x20008000, but rather to `stack + 256` given the OP's fishy array. Otherwise the stack will start in overflow state and start to chew away on the `.data` section the first thing it does.

Comment: I've seen in TI's User Guide that the stack should be places inside the SRAM_RETENTION so I've placed this entire array inside it. I've updated my question with my current linker script and startup files. It still doesn't work by the way, but I feel like it makes more sense now.